# In DevOps pipeline, how can you handle multiple data sources in one analysis services model

Tags: azure-devops, azure-analysis-services

We are building our analysis services model off of an azure sql server data warehouse and a second azure sql server database.  You can easily add multiple data sources in the visual studio AAS model/project.

However, when we setup the devops pipeline i can only add one database connection in the pipeline settings.

[![Devops Pipeline][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhVOb.png

Is there a workaround for handling multiple data sources in one AAS model in Devops?

Comment: Your picture was not added correctly. I could not get the detailed info. If possible, please check if this document give any help: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/managing-configuration-app-settings-for-multiple-environments-in-your-cd-pipeline/

Comment: The link there is to the image  but you would have to browse to that web link.    Let me try this:   [ScreenshotLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhVOb.png)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a workaround for handling multiple data sources in one AAS model in Devops?

I am afraid there is no such way to handle multiple data sources in one AAS model in Devops.

When I check the [source code](https://github.com/liprec/vsts-release-aas/tree/master/deploy-aas-db) for this task, I could get following code:

```
switch ($connectionType) {
    "sql" {
        $model = ApplySQLSecurity -Model $model -Server $sourceSQLServer -Database $sourceSQLDatabase -UserName $sourceSQLUsername -Password $sourceSQLPassword
    }
}
```

It use this command line to create a Database, we could not provide one more datebase name in one command line.

To resolve this issue, you could try to add another task or add a new pipeline for another data source.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So we would setup our 2 data sources in the BIM model file, starting out pointing to DEV.
The DEV pipeline we would setup the dev server connection to one of the data sources.
Deployment of dev is fine since both data sources point to dev in the BIM file.
Next, in the UAT pipeline we can set the UAT server connection to one of the data sources.
What happens when we run the UAT pipeline?  the one data source gets pointed to UAT, while the second data source still points to DEV?  Would we need a custom pipeline task to somehow change that 2nd sql data source connection server?